# android app for tablet of multiple resolutions

Tags: android, tablet, resolutions

How to make an android applications for tablet of multiple resolutions like 1024x600pixels or 1280x800 pixels. I had made an app for the resolution 1024x600 but it completely get distorted on the the tablet of resolution 1280x800...
Any Help....

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Can you post your layout files? (Did you have different ones for different resolutions?)

Comment: No jodes, i m handling the whole layout programmatically for all the activities...

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Replace your "handling the whole layout programmatically for all the activities" with XML layout resources. IMHO, while it is possible to define your UIs totally in Java *and* handle multiple screen sizes, that is a technique reserved for expert Android developers. In other words, if you have to ask "how to make an android applications for tablet of multiple resolutions", then you lack the experience necessary to be "handling the whole layout programmatically for all the activities".

Step #2: Follow the guidance of the Android developer documentation for [supporting multiple screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Step #3: If you still have problems, ask more specific, focused, and longer questions. In other words, explain specifically what your problem is, supply the code/layout XML that is giving you problems, and supply screenshots to illustrate the output you are getting.

Comment: Thanks Commonsware....Agreed that i have much lack of experience dude but 'every expert was first an amateur'. Okiesss no problem I started to work on ur suggestion but at least can you tell me that is it possible to handle this programmatically or not??

Comment: @Gourav Kumar Jain: Since you did not bother to adequately explain your problem, I cannot tell you if it is "possible to handle this programmatically or not". Generally speaking, just about everything in Android can be handled programmatically instead of via XML, but usually with several times the code and significantly increased chance of bugs.